# Query optimization of a view in sql server used for updating daily work status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to optimize this query but I have no clue how.

```
select       
   max(case when EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID = 5519 then EAMT.[TEXT] end) as OnDate      
   ,max(case when EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID =5523  then EAMT.[TEXT] end) as [Description]      
   ,max(case when EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID = 5520 then LTRIM(RTRIM(EAMT.[TEXT])) end) as [Case_URL]      
  ,EAMT.ENTITY_ID      
from ENTITY_ASSOC_METADATA_TEXT EAMT with (nolock)      
where EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID in (      
        select ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID      
        from ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE with (nolock)      
        where Entity_Type_ID in (select Entity_Type_ID       
              from ENTITY_TYPE with (nolock)      
     where Name like '%Daily Work Status%'      
              ) and IS_ACTIVE = 'Y'      
        ) and EAMT.IS_ACTIVE = 'Y'       
Group by Entity_ID
```

I am new to optimization. Currently this query take 5 minutes and 31 seconds. Please help.

Comment: See the execution plan of your query, you will be able to find details of pain points.

Comment: I would suggest providing some information about what indexes are on the underlying tables would help along with rowcounts per table. For example you have a wildcard search on the Name column which if not indexed could cause you performance issues. Check the query plan as well and look for tablescans and large IO operations.

Comment: Do you really need IN with subqueries for your ID fields, maybe some kind of JOIN could be used instead?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson in is not necessary. can you suggest me some joins?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with that but for instance you can do `JOIN ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE EAT ON EAT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID = EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID ...`

Answer (score 1):

I would start by writing this as joins:

```
select EAMT.ENTITY_ID  
       max(case when EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID = 5519 then EAMT.[TEXT] end) as OnDate,      
       max(case when EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID = 5523  then EAMT.[TEXT] end) as [Description],     
       max(case when EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID = 5520 then LTRIM(RTRIM(EAMT.[TEXT])) end) as [Case_URL]      
from ENTITY_ASSOC_METADATA_TEXT EAMT join
     ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE eat
     ON eat.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID = eamt.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID join
     ENTITY_TYPE et
     on et.Entity_Type_ID = eamt.Entity_Type_ID
where et.Name like '%Daily Work Status%' an    
      eam.IS_ACTIVE = 'Y' and   
      EAMT.IS_ACTIVE = 'Y' and
      EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID in (5519, 5523, 5520)     
group by eamt.Entity_ID
```

I'm not sure if this will be faster, but it will give the database more opportunities to optimize the query and use indexes.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
select       
   max(case when EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID = 5519 then EAMT.[TEXT] end) as OnDate      
   ,max(case when EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID =5523  then EAMT.[TEXT] end) as [Description]      
   ,max(case when EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID = 5520 then LTRIM(RTRIM(EAMT.[TEXT])) end) as [Case_URL]      
  ,EAMT.ENTITY_ID      
from ENTITY_ASSOC_METADATA_TEXT EAMT with (nolock)      
where   EAMT.IS_ACTIVE = 'Y' AND
        EXISTS( select 1      
                from ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE  EAT with (nolock)      
                where EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID  =  EAT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID AND
                      EAT.IS_ACTIVE = 'Y' AND
                      EXISTS(select 1
                             from ENTITY_TYPE ET with (nolock) 
                             where EAT.Entity_Type_ID = AND ET.Entity_Type_ID
                             ET.Name like '%Daily Work Status%'))        
Group by Entity_ID
```

Made the couple of changes like

- Replaced `IN` clause with the `EXISTS`
- Changed the ordering of the same conditions

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to tell,
I) How many rows each table contain ?

II) What is the relation between each table ?

III) Query should return how many rows ? If it can return more than thousands then why can't you use paging etc.

Try this,

```
;With CTE as

(
SELECT ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID
FROM dbo.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE A WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM dbo.ENTITY_TYPE B WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE A.Entity_Type_ID= B.Entity_Type_ID 
and B.NAME LIKE '%Daily Work Status%'
)
AND A.IS_ACTIVE = 'Y'
)

-- Test how much time it takes

--select * from CTE 

SELECT max(CASE 
WHEN EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID = 5519
THEN EAMT.[TEXT]
END) AS OnDate
,max(CASE 
WHEN EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID = 5523
THEN EAMT.[TEXT]
END) AS [Description]
,max(CASE 
WHEN EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID = 5520
THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(EAMT.[TEXT]))
END) AS [Case_URL]
,EAMT.ENTITY_ID
FROM dbo.ENTITY_ASSOC_METADATA_TEXT EAMT WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
Exists(
 select 1 
from CTE c 
where c.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID=EAMT.ENTITY_ASSOC_TYPE_ID
)
AND EAMT.IS_ACTIVE = 'Y'
GROUP BY Entity_ID
```

Comment: will discuss index later on after your response.